# Microsoft ReportViewer: group multiple images into sprite

Tags: asp.net, iframe, reporting-services, rdlc, microsoft-reporting

I have an RDLC-report which contains a lot of small images (hundreds).
When I'm opening it using SSRS-portal it groups all images into one sprite, loads it in one call and opens fast.

[image: Sprite image example]

But if I embed it into my asp.net mvc application via iframe using ReportViewer control from Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms package, it simply loads each image separately (making hundreds of calls) and opens very slow.

[image: Separate image example]

[image: Network calls]

I'm using the last version of the ReportViewer control now - 14.0.0.0. But also I've tried older versions without success.
Except this there is no more difference working with this report via SSRS-portal or via my own portal.

Does anybody know how to force it use sprites instead of separate images when you embed it into your own portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I've found that it seems to be a known issue.
Such optimization of images presents in native mode (e.g. when you're using SSRS-portal) and doesn't present in integrated mode (e.g. when you embed report into your portal).

Here are the links where I've found the most important information:

[What’s Up With the Slow SSRS R2 Rendering in SharePoint 2010 Integrated Mode?](https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2011/1/25/whats-up-with-the-slow-ssrs-r2-rendering-in-sharepoint-2010.html)

[The switch back to SSRS Native mode for Performance Reasons](http://dereksan.blogspot.ru/2011/01/switch-back-to-ssrs-native-mode-for.html)

[SSRS 2008 R2 Add-in Performance Issues](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d5a45f9f-92c9-479e-a87b-3268b98cf462/ssrs-2008-r2-addin-performance-issues?forum=sqlreportingservices)